# Aligning effect in uniform field

Tags: thermodynamics, velocity

I would like to discuss the nature of the following effect. At whatever angle and with whatever initial speed the particle fly into a uniform gravitational or electric field, over time the directions of the instantaneous velocity and field strength converge. The kinematics and dynamics here are trivial, but I wondered: is there any general principle (such as the least action) that dictates this effect? Long attempts led me to a very vague "Maximum power principle" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_principle that reinforce production and efficiency." which in relation to this problem can be formulated as follows:

> "the system tends to move to such a movement that the power transfer of energy from potential to kinetic was maximum. It seems to be true, since instantaneous power is defined as the scalar product of force and instantaneous speed..."

Ok, it is necessary using the stationary-action principle show that the vectors of the instantaneous velocity and force over time should approach each other in direction

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.